# How can I run code from an external file on a page rendered from markdown using GatsbyJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm currently building a site using Gatsby which renders pages from markdown files. On certain pages, I want to run code that is contained in an external file. This includes running JavaScript from `foo.js`, importing CSS from `bar.css` and/or displaying HTML from `baz.html`.

Is there a way I can specify dynamically in the markdown that I want to run code from another file?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you mean when you say *dynamically*. It is not possible to use any form of control flow (if, else, etc) with vanilla Markdown. Therefore, you cannot truly *dynamically* import files.

With that in mind, if you simply mean whether or not it is possible to import scripts / styles to Markdown at all, the answer lies in the software you are using to convert the Markdown file to HTML.

First off, as per Markdown [documentation](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html):

> For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply use HTML itself. There’s no need to preface it or delimit it to indicate that you’re switching from Markdown to HTML; you just use the tags.

Therefore, you can try simply adding `<script>` / `<link>` tags as you normally would within HTML. Whether or not this will work for your purposes will depend on how Gatsby's Markdown transformer ([Remark](https://remark.js.org/)) handles the conversion. There may be other internal Gatsby mechanisms to consider, but this should hopefully help as a starting point.

Comment: Would the files have to exist in the public folder to refer to them in a `<script>` or `<link>` tag?

Comment: @MattStobbs There are other ways, but that would be the easiest by a significant amount.